# How do I make auto zoom with jquery

Tags: jquery, effects, jquery-effects, zooming

I need to animate some images with auto zoom effect in a space of time with jQuery. I can`t find a plugin to do that, then I think I got to do this by myself, any ideas to code that?

Comment: Well.. what are your ideas to accomplish this? You need to show us some attempts.

Comment: Like this: http://www.extro-templates.eu/home-3

Answer (score 0):

I would change the height and width and have it transistion to the new pos and or size

```
#id_of_element {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
}
```